# Tirar printscreen no Android pela API

Tags: java, android, api

Tenho um *app* e uma das funções seria tirar *printscreen* da tela.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei este código nessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/221800):

```
//nome e local onde será gravado
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

//cria a imagem
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternativa usando canvas conforme outra resposta no SO:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/PrintScren.java).

Comment: No caso esse código tira um print e salva no SD Card, acho que só a parte do `bitmap` é suficiente. (:

Comment: Sim, ele pode fazer com o resultado o que ele quiser, não necessariamente gravar no SD.

Comment: testei e vi o link que você enviou. Retirei o ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND, não faço ideia o que é isso mas substitui pelo nome+extensão da img (é uma boa por o nome do arquivo como data-hora para não substituir caso tire mais de uma screenshot!!). Tb tive que substituir mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView(); por getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); Pois não estava tirando print e nem mostrando erro. Só que tem um porem, ele tira print somente da activity, não tira da tela do Android por completo

Comment: @FelipeAvelar como faz para deixar uma palavra do comment marcada, tal como vc fez com bitmap?

Comment: @felipe.rce verei se acho mais alguma coisa, para destacar qualquer texto nos posts você usa ele entre crases ` `

Comment: @bigown, consegui tirar printscreen da tela inteira, seguindo o link que você me enviou, só que precisa de root... Então creio que não tem como sem root

Answer (score 2):

Somente para complementar a resposta do Maniero.

Tem uma solução para tirar *print screen* da tela do Android, você pode usar isso em um *service*, mas necessita de *root*:

```
    try {
         Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
         OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
         os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
         os.flush();
         os.close();
         sh.waitFor();
   } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Quando você colocou o comentário, eu ia trazer pra cá esta que era o que eu achei que você tinha utilizado.